# Multiple props in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
const UserInput: React.FunctionComponent<{ text: string, onChange (text: string): void}> = (props, userContent: any) => {
  console.log('12345', userContent.Content) // Only returns undefined if userContent is after props
  return (
    <View>
      <TextInput
      value={props.text}
      mode='outlined'
      placeholder={'Text'}
      onChangeText={props.onChange}
    />
    </View>
  );
}
```

I want it so that when I console.log, it comes back with something not undefined. If I put userContent first in the props, it works fine but the then everything in FunctionComponenet doesn't work. Any ideas? I've tried quite a lot of different ways but can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A functional component only accepts one argument `props`, so a second argument will always be undefined (in your case `userContent`).

You need to access the prop through props like this:

```js
console.log('12345', props.userContent.Content)
```

Or you could destructure it from props like this:

```js
const UserInput = ({userContent, ...props}) => {
  console.log('12345', userContent.Content)
```

It looks like that will also require a change to your interface.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried this but it doesn't seem to work (I get undenfied is not an object). I have added it to the functional component part instead of in the props brackets. `const UserInput: React.FunctionComponent<{ text: string, onChange (text: string): void, userContent: any}> = (props) => {`

Comment: That won't have any effect on this. I'm assuming you're using typescript, that's all that change will effect. If you are still getting undefined, you need to check that you are passing the prop into the component.

Comment: "If I put userContent first in the props, it works fine" - If this is the case, should it just be `props.Content`?

Comment: That worked, don't know what I did different before. Thanks man!